# How do I add timeouts to .contains in Cypress using Typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, cypress

I am trying to convert a working cypress test to typescript.

The following line is flagged as a compile error:

```
cy.contains("here's where you left off...",  {timeout: slowLoader })
```

The error message says:

```
Argument of type '{ timeout: number; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | number | RegExp'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'timeout' does not exist in type 'string | number | RegExp'.
```

slowLoader is defined above as:

```
let slowLoader = 30000; // timeout time for slow loading elements
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking at the documentation I see

```
contains(selector, content, options)
```

could it be that you need to pass in

```
cy.contains("SOME SELECTOR","here's where you left off...", {timeout: slowLoader })
```

Did this test work previously in just JS?

My first thought was use the  keyword to force it

```
cy.contains("here's where you left off...",<any> {timeout: slowLoader }),
```

but I think that is wrong argument position for the options

Comment: That is indeed the wrong argument position. `.contains(selector, content, options);` would imply that a 3-argument `.contains` should be something like 'cy.contains('div', 'here's where you left off...', {timeout: slowLoader});`

Comment: Yes, I agree. I wonder was the test ever working in JS vs TypeScript